# In Word or PPT, how to batch insert pictures in an a array, fitting to cell size?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint

I am writing reports everyday in which I have to attach 9 images in a 3x3 array format, each cell of the same size. Every time, I have to import and resize all images one by one to be squares (6x6cm) and then align them properly as follows:

Array of pictures:
[image: Array of pictures]

This is highly repetitive and time consuming. My pictures shouldn't be cropped but rather fit the cell fixed size. The resolution and proportions are not an issue as they are almost squares from the start.

Is there any way to batch import those 9 images all at once and get them resized and inserted into my array ? I have tried with both Word and PowerPoint placeholders but I cannot find a way around apart from importing them 1 by 1 using SmartArt.

Comment: How're your VBA skills. A not-too-complex VBA macro could do this for you if you don't mind editing it each time to supply the full paths to the images.

Comment: Close to 0 to be honest, I will have a look. Would be even better if that could be parametrized with a single folder path, scanning for the images. Is that something VBA supports?

Comment: Absolutely possible, in a number of ways, but possibly the simplest is well-explained here: https://trumpexcel.com/vba-dir-function/